# Docker Run Command as Sudo?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Inside my dockerfile I have:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
FROM python:latest

RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nmap
```

But I have a problem where the last line doesn't work because of sudo, how may I fix this?

Comment: Your first FROM line does nothing, so you can safely delete it

Comment: @HansKilian why? I want to specefy latest version of ubuntu not macos or linux etc...

Comment: Because for each FROM statement, your image is 'reset' and everything before the last FROM statement is ignored. You only use multiple FROM statements if you want to copy something from an earlier image using `COPY --from=...`. Since you don't do that, your first FROM statement doesn't do anything. `python:latest` is based on `debian:bullseye` so that's what your image also is. There's no easy way to get a python image based on Ubuntu since the python people don't make one.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    nmap
```

`-y` means automatic *"yes"* answer to all prompts and runs non-interactively.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question in anyway, I asked to run it as sudo...

Comment: Not all Linux images come with sudo installed by default. You'll have to install it using apt-get. I don't see any reason why sudo is needed to install nmap. Also, even with sudo, -y option is needed since docker command during build are non-interactive.

Comment: @krskara You don't need sudo, because you're already running as root.

Comment: @HansKilian that's not right, please see my new question

Comment: nmap tells me: You are not root -- using TCP pingscan rather than ICMP

Answer (score 0):

Since your first FROM statement doesn't do anything and you're already running as root, you can change your Dockerfile to

```
FROM python:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nmap
```

Build and run with

```
docker build -t myimage .
docker run -it myimage /bin/bash
```

Now you're in a shell in the container. You can now run `whoami` to verify that you're running as root and you can run nmap.

Comment: You should always `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in a single command, as [@krskara's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71995230) shows.  This avoids a problem if you come back a week later and add a second package to the "install" line: Docker will have cached the "update" line, but it points at specific URLs that get deleted regularly, and the "install" has a reasonable chance of failing.

Comment: @DavidMaze That's true, and I'd normally do that. I opted to keep it as close to the original file as I felt OP was new to Docker and I didn't want to introduce too many changes.